# Pandas dataframe efficient arithmetic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am starting to utilize pandas dataframes a lot and I had a question around arithmetic efficiency.

Most of the time, my dataframes are built out left to right where I append a new column on to the end and the new column is built from values already in the df. For now, it would just be dependent on the row, no aggregations.

My question is, what's the most efficient way to do this? I like to build functions to contain my arithmetic. So do I build a function that takes in single values, and then use

```
.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['col']), axis=1)
```

Or should I make functions that run off of series? Then I can say
`df['new']=my_func(df['col'])`

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly- none of these 2, the best is to leverage vectorized operations using either native ```pandas``` or ```numpy```

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski in fact approach 2 would be the way to go, given it is vectorized. For example, `def myfunc(x): return x**2)` is totally suitable.

Comment: You're right. IF it is.

Comment: So would doing arithmetic on a series level is best?